# Number of tweets by a user in a certain period of time

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Is it possible to know the number of tweets tweeted by a user in certain period of time using twitter4j. If it is not possible to do that, are there any other  APIs which can solve this problem.

Comment: Hey Shree Khanal why dont you answer my question? Are you here just to give negative votes to the questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, by fetching the entire timeline of the user. Once you've got that done, you can filter the `Status`es by the `createdAt` property.
Be careful that Twitter4j has many rate limitation, so it is possible that you won't manage to fetch all the statuses at one time.